# passing values in MIPS macros

Tags: assembly, macros, mips

I've been studying MIPS as an introduction to assembly, and recently started playing with macros.  What I want to be able to do is pass a value generated by another macro, or just any value in any particular register, into another macro. ie,

```
.data

.macro print_int(%x) #this macro prints a given integer %x
li      $v0, 1
li      $a0, %x
syscall
.end_macro

.macro terminate     #this macro terminates a program
li      $v0, 10
syscall
.end_macro

.text
main:

li      $t0, 7       #first, load the value 7 into register t0
print_int($t0)       #then, attempt to pass the value in $t0 through print_int

terminate            #end program
```

this program (specifically the `print_int($t0)` line) does not pass the assembler and turns up as an error.  Is there a proper syntactic way to do this, or is my approach fundamentally incorrect?

Comment: `li $a0, %x` looks wrong. You probably want `mov $a0,%x`

Answer (score 2):

It is never too late to correct a mistake! You have many errors. First of all, you cannot call `li` with a register value as a second parameter. Then, you should use `$x` and not `%x`. Finally, macros are inside the `.text` section (see [MIPS](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/HP_AppA.pdf)). (Note also, that macros are not supported by QtSpim. However, they are supported by MARS.)

```
.text

.macro print_int($x)
#lw $a0, $x #alternative call
la $a0, ($x)
li $v0, 1
syscall
.end_macro

.macro terminate
li $v0,10
syscall
.end_macro

main:

li $t0, 7

print_int($t0) #call print macro!

terminate #end program
```